# Processing lights()

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I was trying to recreate this Menger Sponge, but my light effect is really bad and I can't understand why.
My sponge looks like this:

[image]
I want it to look more like this: https://youtu.be/LG8ZK-rRkXo?t=13m16s

This is how I draw the box:

```
ambientLight(255);
ambientMaterial(250);
box(size);
```

I noticed that instead of using `ambientLight()` he uses `lights()` (in Processing), but I can't find a corresponding function in p5.
Can anyone help me?

---

**UPDATE**: You can now use the built-in [`lights()`](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/lights) function, which was built by me to face this issue ;) ([issue](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/2645) - [pr](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/pull/3553))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can currently improvise and put ambient or point lights together to get a similar effects:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(710, 400, WEBGL);
  noStroke();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  //point light on the right
  pointLight(255, 255, 255, 500, 0, 200);

  //directional light from the left
  directionalLight(255, 255, 255, -1, 0, 0);

  // Yellow spotlight from the front
  pointLight(255, 255, 255, 0, 300, 300);
  ambientMaterial(255);

  rotateY(map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, PI));
  rotateX(map(mouseY, 0, height, 0, PI));
  box(200);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Be sure to check out the other available light types and materials in the [p5.js WebGL wiki](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Getting-started-with-WebGL-in-p5)

If that's still not the look you're after, remember you can easily [integrate p5.js with other libraries](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Integrating-other-libraries), for example [three.js](http://threejs.org).